# How "good" is the new Classify and how does it choose its method

Tags: machine-learning

I recently read the blog regarding data-science [Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/10/10/building-the-automated-data-scientist-the-new-classify-and-predict/) and then checked the quality of the new `Classify`. I have a bunch of slides that I show to my students explaining classification. There I use the Titanic data from Wolfram. Here a screenshot from my slides 2016:
[image: old Classify]

I´m really wondering about the new `Classify`, because I now tried the same notebook with the new Mathematica version... surprise, surprise.

[image: new classify]

The data did not change, I compared with my local copy. So I doubt whether the automated data scientist mentioned in the blog has actually arrived ;-)

`Classify` (new) has chosen a different method which delivers a worse accuracy. So there should be other parameters on which `Classify` chooses the method. Does anyone know on what parameters this decision is made?